# command to clean tmp directory on my web server

Tags: php, linux, file

I was getting `write failed: No space left on device (28)` in my websites.
So I checked my tmp size using ssh and it was 100% full.

What command can I use through ssh to free up space in the tmp directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the file inside the tmp directory just go to the tmp directory

```
cd tmp/
```

and run the following command

```
rm -rf ./
```

It will delete all the directories inside that directory.

and

```
rm -rf *.*
```

It will delete all the files inside that directory.

Comment: Once I destroyed my site deleting all session files in /tmp folder. I don't know why but it stopped working. After restoring them I deleted only files older then 1 month

Comment: If you only delete the /tmp folder files. it will not affect anything. Please check it properly

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the files

`rm -rf /path/to/tmp/*`

You need to adjust `/path/to/tmp` with the path to your directory containing the temp files.

**Warning:** Please keep in mind, that all removed files are truly removed (= lost). So check all parameters first, before using this command.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /tmp
rm -fr *
```

With PHP I don't know if you have permission to delete the files:

```
$files = glob('/tmp/*');
foreach($files as $file){
   if(is_file($file)){
       unlink($file);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this command. It *shows* the files?

(replace /tmp/ if this is not the folder you wanted to clean up)

```
find /tmp/ -mtime +6 -exec ls   {} \;
```

Edit your cron table:

```
$> crontab -e
```

Add a line:

```
* 6 * * * find /tmp/ -mtime +6 -exec rm -r   {} \;
```

To permanently *delete* all files (daily) in /tmp, that are a handfull of days old.

Answer (score 0):

**rm -rf tmp/**

Recursively deletes the directory tmp, and all files in it, including subdirectories. And better be careful with this command!!

Answer (score 0):

To overcome your problem do what one of the posters has suggested.

But to avoid it in the future set up a `cron` job to tidy up periodically.

Look into using `find` system command to find old files that can be safely deleted (i.e. temporary files that will not be in use).